# OnClick events and iPhone/iPad -> flashing overlay?

Tags: iphone, onclick

I have a website with several elements that use the onclick event. When I 'click' on them on the iPhone/iPad there is a dark overlay that shortly flashes over the element.
Is it possible to disable this effect?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: I also want to find the solution for this

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990442/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-flash-blink-on-the-ipad-iphone-when-an-onclick-is
I think this resolved my problem back then...