# Is there a way to disable the flash/blink on the iPad/iPhone when an onclick is fired?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

So I have an area that has an onclick event. When clicked on a regular browser it does not show any visual change, but when it is clicked on the iPad/iPhone it makes a flash/blink. Is there any way to stop it from doing this on the iPad/iPhone?

Here is an example similar to what I am doing: http://jsfiddle.net/zb5xn/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
body * {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Are there any "gotchas" against making this a default rule; as part of the CSS reset/normalize?